# Asynchronous code inside an for each loop

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, foreach

This is my first post, because I usually find a way to answer my questions via the old messages... But this time I'm stuck. I hope you can help me.

```
searchUser.forEach(function(item, i) {
        getUser(item)
        .then(objUser => {
            console.log(i);
            console.log(objUser);
            name = objUser.name;
            let idConversation = objUser.id;
            createNewConversation(name, idConversation)
        })
    })
```

My `getUser` is an asynch function, and I don't know why, but it seems that my construction does not work. it only creates the number of conversations i have but with the content of the last conversation and not the others... any idea of what I'm missing there? by the way `console.log(i)` gives `1` and then `0`.

FYI the `getUser` is a *function* that **returns** data from the user.

Comment: witout using a keyword (`let`/`const`/`var`) in front of the `name` variable, you are setting the variable outside of the callback function's scope

Comment: True! Thank you Constantin, but this does not change the problem.

Comment: use an array or an object to store the result of each iteration

Comment: createNewConversation(name, idConversation) method creates conversations  with name and id?? can you show how that method is implemented?

Comment: Actually I simplified a bit the example. the createNewConversation works fine. The issue is on the async getUser in a for Each loop. And my getUser has also another callback inside...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having an async function inside a forEach loop can be tricky to debug, i would suggest using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to call `createNewConversation` after all of the promises are resolved :

```
const promises = searchUser.map(item => getUser(item));

Promise.all(promises).then(result => {
  result.forEach(({ name, id }) => {
    createNewConversation(name, id);
  });
});
```

Comment: I still have the same problem that with my construction... it creates the number of conversations i have but with the content of the last conversation and not the others. Could my problem be somewhere else and I did not see it?

Comment: probaby, `console.log` the `name` and the `id` before you call `createNewConversation` to see if you're calling it with the same `id` and `name`

Comment: I have another callback inside my searchUser function. I think this could come from this point. What do you think?

Comment: could be .. can't really answer that without knowing that other callback